# Difference between DateTimeFormatter.Format() and string

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

The return value of [DateTimeFormatter.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.format) should be a string. But when trying to parse the result of the DateTimeFormatter string (e.g. the day part in a new DateTime object) it throws an `"System.FormatException"`.

Example code:

```
private void TestDateTimeFormatter()
{
    var forlatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("day");
    var casualDayFormat = forlatter.Format(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1));
    Console.WriteLine(casualDayFormat); // result is "1"
    var casualDateTime1 = DateTime.Parse("1" + ".1.2018"); //Works
    var casualDateTime = DateTime.Parse(casualDayFormat + ".1.2018"); //Throws wrong format exception
    Console.WriteLine(casualDateTime);
}
```

Something doesn't add up. Almost certainly there is no difference between `casualDayFormat` (It's a string, and has the value "1") and the string `"1"`. But why it's throwing an exception?

**Edit: Exception Details**

Stack-Trace:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
       at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
//user-code
```

Exception _message:

> One of the identified items was in an invalid format.

Other methods:

Event int.Parse(...) does not work with the string:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
```

Comment: starts to get interesting. can you add the full exception with stack trace?

Comment: Added the exception details. That's all I got from the exception.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `DateTime.Parse(casualDayFormat + ".1.2018");` in your real code and not by accident `DateTime.Parse(casualDayFormat1 + ".1.2018");` or similar?

Comment: 100% sure. Tried also `int.Parse(casualDayFormat)` (updated the post for the exception message)

Comment: Last ditch effort :) Check whether your casualDayFormat string has leading and/or trailing spaces/tabs/new-lines/etc...

Comment: It is a WinRT class, likely written in C++, you can't assume it does what DateTime.ToString() will do.  My crystal ball says that there is an invisible Unicode codepoint in that string, like a Left-to-Right Mark.  The debugger won't show it unless you use casualDayFormat.ToCharArray() in the watch expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to HansPassant I found the problem. When converting the string to a char array, I can clearly see the hidden 8206 (left-to-right) mark inserted in the string.

[image]

When removing that char from the string with:

```
string output = new string(casualDayFormat.Where(c => c < 128).ToArray());
```

The parsing works again like a charm. However, as a C# dev, I would no except such a behaviour from the WinRT-API.

Comment: [related social msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SharePoint/en-US/8be0cde0-8fd1-4e22-b7f3-82b72395f260/why-does-windowsglobalizationdatetimeformattingdatetimeformatter-include-lefttoright-mark-e2-80?forum=winappswithhtml5)

Comment: The same 8206 characters are present when using the C++/WinRT version from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter?view=winrt-22621